# solving system of 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any nice/elegant ways to solve this system of equations?

$\left\{\begin{matrix} 2x^2+xy+y^2=28 & \\ x^2-xy+2y^2=32 & \end{matrix}\right.$

I can solve it by isolating one of the variables but it's too messy.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add the two equations together to get rid of the $xy$ term.

Comment: @crf - that's what i did for the isolation method.

Answer (score 5):

There is a general way to solve such homogeneous equations.

First note that $x=0$ doesn't provide a solution. Now choose $m=\dfrac{y}x$, so that $y=mx$. Your two equations then become,

$x^2(2+m+m^2)=28
\\ x^2(1-m+2m^2)=32$

Dividing the two, we obtain:

\begin{align}
&\dfrac{2+m+m^2}{1 -m+2m^2}=\dfrac78\\
&\iff 2m^2-5m-3=0\\
&\iff (2m+1)(m-3)=0.
\end{align}

For $m=-\dfrac12$, $x^2=16$ while for $m=3$, we get $x^2=2$.

Thus, $(x,y) \in\{\,(4,-2),\,(-4,2),\,(\sqrt2,3\sqrt2),\,(-\sqrt2,-3\sqrt2)\,\}$.

Comment: nice+, btw what do you mean by a general way?

Comment: @gazok This method of using the substitution $y=mx$, also works for other homogeneous equations.

Comment: oh by homogeneous you mean $F(tx,ty)=t^nF(x,y)$. ill check it next time! thanks.

Comment: @gazok Yes. Basically for a polynomial, the sum of the powers of all the variables in each term should be the same.

Comment: in a system it has to add up to the same sum of powers? like $6$ in this case for each equation? or $2$ in each term in each equation?

Comment: @gazok $2$ in each term. You're essentially just factoring out an $x^2$ and the remaining expression is a quadratic in $\dfrac{y}x$ because the sum of the powers of $x$ and $y$ in each term is $2$. So then, you can divide the two equations, to obtain a quardatic in $\dfrac{y}x$ and solve the system.

Comment: got it very nice approach thanks!

Comment: @PeterPhipps Thank you very much for correcting my foolish mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding one equation to the other: eqn. 1 + eqn.2 
\begin{align*}
(2x^2 + xy + y^2) + (x^2 - xy + 2y^2) &= 28 + 32\\
3x^2+3y^2 &= 60\\
x^2 + y^2 &=20\tag{*}
\end{align*}

And from linear algebra we now, that points $[x,y] \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfy (*) are located on a circle with center in $[0,0]$ and radius $\sqrt{20}$.

Because general equation for a circle in plane is
$$
(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2.
$$

Where $[x_0,y_0] \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the center of the circle and $r$ is radius.

Comment: there are infinite points that satisfy that circle. from $(*)$ i isolated one of the variable and substituted in one of the equation. that's how i got the solutions. im looking for different approach or i just didn't understand yours.

Comment: And what is wrong with infinitely many points that satisfy the system of equations? Consider system of equation
$$y = 2,$$
but in a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Every pair $[t,2] \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ solves this system, because in fact the system is equivalent to
$$
0 \cdot x + y = 2
$$

Comment: well, because there are no infinite solutions the this system..
so i don't know how you can proceed from that circle. let's say $x^2=1$ so $y^2=19$ putting that in equation 1, and it's not true.

Comment: My bad, sorry, I didn't finish the idea correctly. I would continue the same way you wrote (isolation and substitution). So no help at all from my side.

Comment: no problem but thanks for the effort.